# What is the difference between List<T> and List(Of T) in c#

Tags: c#

I am confused why Microsoft documentation sometimes refer to the List class as `List<T>` and sometimes `List(Of T)`.

Comment: Can you cite where you've seen this? I'm curious, as I've never seen `List(Of T)` before.

Comment: List(Of T) is a VB.Net syntax, (in MSDN, be sure you are in c# tab, not on a vb tab)

Comment: Yes you are right. Actually it was showing c# tab but I had to click on another tab then c# tab again to show List<T>.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
List(Of T)
```

is VB.NET syntax, and is the same as C#

```
List<T>
```

You will see it a lot in the MS documentation, because they will usually show sample code in both VB.NET and C#. You just need to pay attention to which one they are talking about.

Comment: @BradRem - there is absolutely no need for comments telling someone to accept a particular answer, please don't do it.